# Reading an Excel spreadsheet of Regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm creating a program to parse data. My dictionary is growing quite long. Therefore, I'd like to save it as a file that can be read in. Preferably xlsx, but a txt file will work too. Besides cleaning up the program, this will also allow me to call different dictionaries depending on what data is to be extracted.

The dictionary that looks like this:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

my_Dict = {   
    'cat': re.compile(r'CAT (?P<cat>.*)\n'),  
    'dog': re.compile(r'DOG (?P<dog>.*)\n'),
    'mouse': re.compile(r'MOUSE (?P<mouse>.*)\n'),    
}
```

What's the best format to put this in an xlsx or txt form to make it most easily readable? Then how you read it in to use as a dictionary?

I've been able to write this dictionary to a file, but it never reads back in how I just wrote it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a Comma Separated Value (.csv) file. You can treat it as a plain text file or open it in Excel without much difficulty.

Your dict would look like:

```
cat, CAT (?P<cat>.*)\n
dog, DOG (?P<dog>.*)\n
mouse, MOUSE (?P<mouse>.*)\n
```

As far as reading it, you would just need to loop over the lines and separate them at the comma, using the first part as the key and the second as the value.

```py
my_dict = {}

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        # Split the line on the comma
        split_line = line.split(',')

        # .strip() removes either specified characters or, if not argument is given,
        # leading and trailing whitespace
        my_dict[split_line[0].strip()] = re.compile(split_line[1].strip())
```

However, if you need to include commas in your regexes or names, this will break. In that case, a Tab Seperated Value (.tsv) file would probably work. Instead of splitting on `','`, you would instead split on `'\t'`.

If neither of these work, you can split on just about any arbitrary character, however MS Excel will recognize and be able to open both .csv and .tsv files readily.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. For some reason the last line in the script give me a syntax error? I've tried fixing it. However, I keep ending up with the same problem I had with all the other solutions I've found. Namely, it's not being read in with the format I have show:'cat': re.compile(r'CAT (?P<cat>.*)\n'), Something always changes when I read it in such that it doesn't behave as the same dictionary.

Comment: Sorry about that, I misplaced a bracket. Updated to the desired format

Comment: Hi ray_of_sunshine, Thanks for making the change! It'll help other who come along. I believe I had corrected it and my problem was understanding the nuances of the raw strings. In the csv we're not defining the the raw strings as I did (r'). However, it does seem to be reading them in and converting them. My list isn't as pretty as the one I shown. I have things like; V\+ and \* that when read in go to V\\+ and \\* as they should. I would still rather be able to define them that way. Do you know how? I have an uneasy feeling this will come back and haunt me as my dictionaries grow.

Comment: When reading files with python you will always be taking in the exact characters typed in the file. You can think about the file as one big raw string. Python allows you to write strings where things like \n gets converted to a newline both as convenience for the user as well as so that it can parse the code properly when running.